# How to create/write to a file asynchronously from an ASMX endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I'm vexed by this issue.

It all started because we log way too much, meaning people would write the textual contents of the request/response dto's (mostly xml) to the log file, thus rendering the file useless to read casually.

My idea was to take what they were inserting into the log file, and instead  stream it to a network filer (another problem, but manageable). Ultimately, the log statement would included the path to the file that was streamed, and if you wanted to open it, have at it.

Here's **version 1**:

```
private static void WriteFileAsync(string path, string text)
{
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => File.WriteAllText(path, text))
        .ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            Log.Error(tsk.Exception, "FileExtensions.PersistPayload");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Version 1 worked well initially, and my testing showed that it was at least being done on another thread, but that was about it. I couldn't verify if this helped or hindered the performance of the web application and the logging [sub-subsystem](https://serilog.net/) but at least the huge amount of text was being removed from the log statement and replaced with the path to the file.

**Version 2**: Was an attempt to use the built in File object and write it asynchronously, which it turns out isn't really the case, or that it is buffered.

```
private static async void WriteFileAsync(string path, string text)
{
    using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(text);
    }
}
```

**Version 3**: Is when I went to using a stream to help create the file. The key to writing this method was something @StephenCleary had in one of his posts or answers on SO, the stream isn't async unless you use the FileStream constructor that takes the param 'useAsync' as outlined below.

```
private static async Task WriteFileAsync(string path, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    }
}
```

So far I'm happy with setup, and have it in a number of ASP.NET MVC 5 applications. However, some of these web projects *349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21* have WCF endpoints hanging off of them and others have ASMX endpoints. If you invoke the asmx file method this exception is thrown:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. 
> Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. 
> If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. 
> This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing.
> ```

So my question is this : "Is there a way to write the file asynchronously and have it work in Web API Controller, WCF endpoint, and an WebService endpoint without dying?"

**Update**

Well, I don't think it's possible to get the asmx handler to do it without a bit of code. I've used code from Wintelects Jeff Prosise, that actually does swap out the default asmx handler for a STA handler which supported async, but that seems like overkill.. I'm just not going to support the asmx file and move forward.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: The method isn't the issue, variant 3 should work fine. If your using webforms you need to mark the page as async like the error says and register your async method. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)

Comment: @JSteward We're not using web forms, these are strictly services and or controllers.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls your logging method from the asmx file?

Comment: @JSteward I don't see how that's relevant, plus it's buried quite a few layers deep in a service. Let's just say that the same code is used in a *.svc file and it works correctly.

Comment: I would think it's relevant since you get the error only when the `WebMethod` is invoked. If your logging method works fine everywhere else then your problem is likely due to the handling of async operations in the older Asp.net frameworks. As for _buried_, maybe you can create an MCVE that reproduces the same error.

Comment: @JSteward I think the answer to my question is NO, you can't do async in an asmx because it's pipeline does not support async, like it's aspx counterpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing code from an MSDN article (Wicked Code) from Wintelects Jeff Prosise where the current asmx HTTP Handler is removed and replaced by one that hooks into the ASPX Page life-cycle, which can work asynchronously. Long term I am migrating away from the old asmx technology.